# Doesn't Immutability Come at the Cost of Speed?

Tags: javascript, redux

I don't know why I can't find an answer to this, but, with state managers requiring immutability, doesn't this come at a significant performance slowdown for large states? I am building an app for fun that wouldn't have arrays large enough to cause a problem (n would max out around a thousand or so, maybe, in extreme cases, a couple thousand).

But, lets say that the app had to keep a gigantic store of information in memory for some reason in state. Every time you have to edit one object, that would mean you have to completely reconstruct the array.

I'm just thinking that, maybe in the future I would need to have states that store such an amount of data, although I can't necessarily think of a concrete example where you would require a state manager to handle it for you. I'm just curious, is there any example where this weird hypothetical of having a huge state happens.
On a side note, the only reference I could find of immutability affecting speed is in increasing it, but this was on the note of reference equality being used for comparison. But wouldn't mutating data have nothing to do with whether you can compare the reference of the object or not?

Comment: fyi usually use a lot of helpers to wrap immutability and increase performance under the covers

Comment: the problem with "wouldn't mutating data have nothing to do with whether you can compare the reference of the object or not" is I think that `redux` cannot detect whether your state changed or not. therefore it has to be immutable and being rebuilt entirely on changes.

Comment: I'm not a researcher in this subject, but generally speaking "speed" is measured *relatively*. There are ops you can do way faster when everything is immutable (think distributed systems) and ops that are basically impossible with immutability when RAM is very small or non-existent (think hardware devices). Your question isn't flawed per se, but I think the implications you're leading to are premature. read some clojure docs for a good time https://clojure.org/reference/transients

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding how immutable updates work.

A correct immutable update doesn't require deep-cloning all objects.  It's more like a nested shallow clone.  Only the set of objects that actually have to be updated get copied, not all of them.

If I want to update `state.items[5].completed`, I need to make a copy of the `item` object at index 5, the `items` array, and `state`.  All the other objects in the `items` array, and all the other sections of `state`, remain untouched.

There certainly is some amount of cost to copying those objects, but for the most part it's not meaningful unless they're exceptionally large.